# How to convert Either<Error, Task<any>> into TaskEither<Error, any> in fp-ts

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have a pipe that return `Either<Error, Task<any>>` but what I need is `TaskEither<Error, any>`.

How can I convert `Either<Error, Task<any>>` to `TaskEither<Error, any>`?

Is there any helper any utility function for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following conversion:

```
import { Either } from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import { Task } from "fp-ts/lib/Task";
import { fromEither, rightTask, chain } from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/pipeable";

type MyType = { a: string }; // concrete type instead of any for illustration here

declare const t: Either<Error, Task<MyType>>; // your Either flying around somewhere

const result = pipe(
  fromEither(t), // returns TaskEither<Error, Task<MyType>>
  chain(a => rightTask(a)) // rightTask returns TaskEither<Error, MyType>, chain flattens
); 

// result: TaskEither<Error, MyType>
```

PS:  I would have liked to just write `chain(rightTask)`, but the `Error` type is not inferred properly with this short-hand (note entirely sure why at the moment).

Nonetheless, that is a cheap price for these strong types and delivers your wanted result!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here:

https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/1072#issuecomment-570207924

```
declare const a: E.Either<Error, T.Task<unknown>>;

const b: TE.TaskEither<Error, unknown> = E.either.sequence(T.task)(a);
```